# Can a function return another function in C?

Tags: c

I’m trying to figure out what a program’s output is. There are two functions, function1 and function2. The first function has an if statement and when the condition is not met, it returns function2. Function2 is similar but it returns itself ‘function2’ when the condition is not met. Any ideas what would happen in this scenario?
If a function returns another function, is the second function executed? 
What about a function returning itself?

I apologize for not being more specific. Here is what I meant to say:

```
int function1(int n) {
    if(n==0){
        return 1;
    }
    return function2(n, 1);
}

int function2(int c, int, s) {
    if(c==1) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return function2(c-1, s*c);
    }
}
```

What I do not understand is what happens when function1 is called and it returns funciton2? Is function2 called? And if it is, and the condition is not met, then does it keep calling itself until the condition is met, and 's' is returned?

Comment: Are you referring to recursion? A function that returns the result of calling itself is a recursive function, but I haven't seen a case when a function returns address of another function.

Comment: Does it return the function itself, or the result of calling the function? Please post the code instead of describing it.

Comment: @Gaurav I think it's worth being precise here and saying that a function that returns _the result of calling itself_ is a recursive function. (Unless functional programming or something has a different sense of recursion)

Comment: Yes any function can return a _function pointer_. The use for the things you describe are quite limited however. A program like the one you describe needs to be re-designed so that it doesn't contain needless complexity and obfuscation.

Comment: It's possible that a function returns another function, but not itself.

Comment: Please put the code snippet here for us to help. From the description, you are probably trying to use recursion.

Comment: I have edited my post. Hope it makes it more clear. And I would appreciate any input!

Answer (score 3):

> Can a function return another function?

I think that what you really mean is: Can a function return the result of another function?

And the answer is yes. Returning a function is also possible using pointers but I doubt that what you want to do.

> Function2 is similar but it returns itself ‘function2’ when the condition is not met.

Function2 is a recursive function. That's a function that calls itself to compute the result. For example, the `exponentiate` function can be computed this way:

```
function exponentiate(x, n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * exponentiate(x, n - 1);
    }
}
```

(if the condition is not met, call the same function with different arguments)

> The first function has an if statement and when the condition is not met, it returns function2.

Function1 simply calls Function2 if needed.

Comment: Downvoter: please explain what's wrong in my answer so I can improve it.

Comment: OP was asking about functions returning other functions, not calling other functions.

Comment: I believe that OP is a beginner that doesn't really understand functions yet and the title is misleading. I decided to ignore the title and focus on the body of the question.

Comment: In other words your answer is about recursive calling the function. OP wants to return the function f2 in f1.

Comment: I made the post from my phone and I didn't have the code with me at the time, so I tried to explain it as best as I could. I just edited my post and I hope it is clearer now. And I appreciate everyone taking the time to pitch in!

Comment: @danglingpointer OP has edited his answer, it's about recursion.

Comment: @melpomene OP was not asking about functions returing other functions, see his edit.